# How to get JSON data by POST method with Secret code in android studio

Tags: java, android, json, post, retrofit

I need to get json data response based on SECRET CODE with POST method, would you please solve my issue, thanks in advance.

I have been facing  with many problems with this POST method of Secret Code to get the JSON Response

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewHeroes);


    getQuestions();
}

private void getQuestions() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiInterface.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
            .build();

    ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel();
    requestModel.setSecretCode("341977082");

    Call<List<ModelObjects>> call = api.getQuestions();

   call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelObjects>>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<List<ModelObjects>> call, Response<List<ModelObjects>> response) {
           List<ModelObjects> questionsList = response.body();


           String[] questions = new String[questionsList.size()];


           for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.size(); i++) {
               questions[i] = questionsList.get(i).getQues_No();
           }



           listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, questions));
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<List<ModelObjects>> call, Throwable t) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });}}
```

Here is the interface and where I am passing the URL that contains parent and extension

```
public interface ApiInterface {

String BASE_URL = "";

@POST("QuestionsList")
Call<List<ModelObjects>> getQuestions();}
```

Here is the response Model

```
 public class ModelObjects {
@SerializedName("Ques_No")
private String Ques_No;

public ModelObjects(String ques_No) {
    Ques_No = ques_No;
}

public String getQues_No() {
    return Ques_No;
}

public void setQues_No(String ques_No) {
    Ques_No = ques_No;
}}
```

Here is the Request Model

```
 public class RequestModel {
private String SecretCode;

public RequestModel(String secretCode) {
    SecretCode = secretCode;
}

public RequestModel() {

}

public String getSecretCode() {
    return SecretCode;
}

public void setSecretCode(String secretCode) {
    SecretCode = secretCode;
}}
```

Comment: this would be the JSON
  [{
    "Ques_No": 1,
    "Question": "Linnaeus system of classification is ",
    "Option1": "Natural",
    "Option2": "Artificial",
    "Option3": "Phylogenetic ",
    "Option4": "Progressive",
    "Answer": "Artificial",
    "Secret_Code": null
  },
  {
    "Ques_No": 2,
    "Question": "The basic unit of classification is ",
    "Option1": "genus",
    "Option2": "Species",
    "Option3": "Variety",
    "Option4": "subspeices",
    "Answer": "Species",
    "Secret_Code": null
  }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have defined `RequestModel` but you are not passing it to the api call. Post request should have body. 
So specify `@Body` while defining the api call as below.

```
@POST("QuestionsList")
Call<List<ModelObjects>> getQuestions(@Body RequestModel model);
```

Then while calling the `getQuestion()` pass the model.

```
RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel();
requestModel.setSecretCode("341977082");
Call<List<ModelObjects>> call = api.getQuestions(requestModel);
```

Update :
update your `ModelObject` as below.

```
public class ModelObjects {
@SerializedName("Ques_No")
String Ques_No;
@SerializedName("Question")
String Ques;
@SerializedName("Answer")
String answer;
//same for other params as well
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply, I did as you suggested. Its connected, but how can I access the first question, woud you please tell me

Comment: You are not able to get any value for the response list? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Yes, Im not able to access any value, but connection is success its code 200

Comment: As per JSON response, your response object has multiple value but I can see you are just parshing only one value which is `Ques_No`.  For other data you need to parse them first. Check my updated answer.

Comment: If i get one value first, then i will access all the json objects. please tell me how to access first json object

Comment: can you confirm the response you are getting by just printing the logs?

Comment: I mean print "response.body()"

Comment: that is  size = 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215178/discussion-between-manjunath-and-durga-m).

Comment: Please change the api call to "Call<JsonArray>". change the method as "public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) { Log.d("tag", response.body())}". This should give you valid response and share the same. Then only we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

What can i see it, you are creating object of RequestModel class, but you are not passing it anywhere. If you want to send the secretCode along with the post network call, then you'll have to pass this requestModel instance to the call.

```
    public interface ApiInterface {
    String BASE_URL = "";
    @POST("QuestionsList")
    Call<List<ModelObjects>> getQuestions(@Body RequestModel requestModel);
    }
```

then you can call this method and can pass this requestModel Object by

```
    Call<List<ModelObjects>> call = api.getQuestions(requestModel);
```

If you want to access the first object you can do it by

```
   List<ModelObjects> questionsList = response.body();
   ModelObject obj = questionList.get(0);
   String question = obj.getQues_No();
```

This question is going to be the first question.

Comment: Siddharth thank for your reply, I wrote the code which you replied, would you please tell me how to access the first object

Comment: Do you want to access the first object from response list?

Comment: Yes Siddharth, I need